# Trying to look for a lower bound on distance between distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, bounded-variation

I have two distributions $X$ and $Y$, is it true that for any arrangement of $X$ and $Y$ values $d= \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_j-y_j)^2$ follows $d\geq\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-y_i)^2$ where $x_i$ and $y_i$ are the $i$th biggest frequencies in the corespondening distribution?

To clearify the $x_j$, $y_j$ arrangements of $X$ and $Y$ are some random arrangements. i hope thats clear enough... if not let me know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is true, this is the rearrangement inequality http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality . Notice that your sum of squared differences is equal to $C - 2 \sum_i x_i y_i$ where $C$ is a constant sum of squares that does not depend on the arrangement. So you want to minimize $-\sum_i x_i y_i$ which is equivalent to maximizing $\sum_i x_i y_i$, which the rearrangement inequality says is maximized when $x_i$ and $y_i$ are in the same order.

Comment: Are you sure? they are talking about multipication and im talking about the square of the diffrence, can you reduce the original problem to a form that it will be the same as the input for the rearrengement problem?

Comment: If you expand the sum of square difference, you get a constant sum of squares plus a constant sum of squares, minus two times a sum of non-squared terms, and the non-squared terms are exactly what's handled by the rearrangement inequality.

Comment: I added this elaboration to my answer

Comment: this is beautiful thanks alot!